# SCP example in Golang

Tags: ssh, go, scp

I spent 3 hours googling for working SCP implementation in Go

I can't find any working lib or example.

This gist is not working. It is buggy but listed in some answers as working code.
https://gist.github.com/jedy/3357393

Comment: You'll probably get a lots of downvotes. State what is 'not working', state what you've expected, copy the code into the question (don't put a link here) and you might have a better chance to get a usefull answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most advanced [SCP client implementation](https://github.com/viant/afs/tree/master/scp) in go.

Beside regular CRUD operations, it also supports batch upload, symbolic links and modification time preservation.

```
    var config *ssh.ClientConfig
    //load config ...

    timeoutMS := 15000
    service, err := scp.NewStorager("127.0.0.1:22", timeoutMS, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    location := "/tmp/myfile"
    err = service.Upload(ctx,  location, 0644, []byte("somedata"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    reader, err := service.Download(ctx,  location)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using it, but a search for SCP on godoc got me [scp-go](https://github.com/laher/scp-go). http://godoc.org/github.com/laher/scp-go/scp

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple 
https://github.com/tmc/scp

Code snippet for copying a local file to remote machine using scp is below

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"

    "github.com/tmc/scp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func getKeyFile() (key ssh.Signer, err error) {
    //usr, _ := user.Current()
    file := "Path to your key file(.pem)"
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    key, err = ssh.ParsePrivateKey(buf)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    key, err := getKeyFile()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Define the Client Config as :
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "root",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeys(key),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error {
            return nil
        },
    }
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "<remote ip>:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
    }

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
    }
    err = scp.CopyPath("local file path", "remote path", session)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to Copy: " + err.Error())
    }
    defer session.Close()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Katiyman, Is this library can be use for copying file from remote to local?